# How to prevent debugger bar from appearing in Xcode 7?

Tags: ios, macos, debugging, xcode7

**The problem**

I'm not sure how to prevent the debugger bar from appearing/disappearing for certain files. This is an issue that has occurred ever since I started using Xcode 7.

**Why it is a problem**

Two to three lines are selected in the editor after I tap in it, to switch from/to the assistant editor, as show in the attached image below.

[image]

**Here is what I know about the issue so far:**

1. I've looked online, and found no information on the issue.
2. The issue still occurs if I elect to show the Assistant Editor on the right.
3. Some files do not cause the debugger to show.
4. Even if I choose to hide the debugger in Behaviors, the issue still occurs.
5. If I use the activation button to show the debugger, and then try to drag it down, the bar sticks at the bottom, and does not disappear.
6. For files that don't show the debugger bar, I'm able to drag the debugger down and it hides completely.
7. This does not happen on Xcode 6.4.
8. This occurs on both OSX and iOS projects.

**Ideal Solution**

I'm looking for a way to hide the debugger completely, so that the editor doesn't freak out and select lines when I tap inside it. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: This is driving me nuts. Funny nobody talks about it. The way I found around it - not a solution - was to have the debug area always visible at the bottom of the screen. This way, when I click on the assistant editor the debug bar does not disappear, and I don't get the freaking 3 lines getting selected.

Comment: @RodrigoPedroso I'm doing that too, but it sucks if you're working on a small screen.

Answer (score 1):

After more experimenting in Xcode, I found a fix.

**Here are the steps for anyone else who is having the same issue:**

> 1. Delete the UI Testing target
> 2. If you are using UI Testing in the project, then re-create the UI Test target, and files will no longer show the debugger bar.

I went through a lot of permutations before finding this, and nothing else had any effect. However, I'm not sure how long this fix will last, since whatever bug in Xcode caused it to occur in the first place could cause it to surface again. This is especially true for projects that have a large amount of UI Testing.

**Edit**

The debugger bar does reappear for a new file, even after adding the UI Testing target had been removed and re-created for the project. This happens even if the new file isn't a view object.

Answer (score 0):

The Xcode debugging tools are integrated throughout the Xcode main window but are primarily located in the Debug area, the debug navigator, the breakpoint navigator, and the source editor. The debugging UI is dynamic; it reconfigures as you build and run your app. To customize how Xcode displays portions of the UI, choose Xcode Preferences > Behaviors.

Comment: Hi, I found the issue, and just submitted an answer for the fix. Behaviors didn't solve the issue--apparently it was related specifically to the UI Testing targets.